# How to create a function that loads "modules"

Tags: javascript, node.js

So I'm creating a simple resource for a game called **FiveM**, anyways I have a folder called utils, and it has sub-folders for each "module" all of them including a file name **this.js**, which have custom functions like logging etc... all that done with module.exports, so my question is how I would go on to create a function to load a specified mod, I've got most of it all I can't seem to get to work is it actually loading...

So far I got:

```js
const fs = require( 'fs' )
const path = require( 'path' )

const MOD = ( mod ) => {
    /*
    * Load them mods into memory
    * */

    fs.access( path.join( __dirname, `..\\${mod}\\this.js` ), fs.F_OK, ( err ) => {
        if ( err )
            return console.error( `Module ${mod} @ utils\\${mod} does not exist!` )

        console.log( `Loaded ${mod} @ utils\\${mod}` )
        return require( path.join( __dirname, `..\\${mod}\\this.js` ) )
    } )
}

exports.MOD = MOD
```

```
MOD( 'colors' )

LOG( `${ Colors.yellow } Hello, it works!` )
```

Output:

> Error loading script fivem.js in resource gus-rp: ReferenceError:
> Colors is not defined

What I've noticed is that I need to pass the function in brackets, if I can't be understood, here's what I mean

```js
const { Function } = require( 'path/to/function' )
```

Which would mess me up if I had a lot of function in let's say `/utils/logging/this.js`

How can I load all module.exports in a file?

Comment: Using the brackets in the way you've shown { Function } is called destructuring. This is likely happening because in the file 'path/to/function' you are doing module.exports = { Function }; or something to that effect. Sounds like you may have your exports in each file done incorrectly which is causing this. It may be more help to provide more of your code, consider putting up a codesandbox or more of the files so your question can be better understood

Comment: Here you go: https://github.com/iWanheda/1 I'm really sorry I had to upload a .rar, my Git has 2FA and my phone's screen ain't working, sorry! (I couldn't log to git in PC, so I uploaded via web)

Answer (score 0):

To load all the exports in a file you need to export them all. Standard pattern is

```
module.exports = { Function1, Function2 };
```

And then on the file you want to use them on

```
const moduleFile = require(‘module.js’);
moduleFile.Function1();
moduleFile.Function2();
```

Please note you need to load the file to the variable you want to use for it to work. Your MOD loader function will not make files accessible in other files by loading mod unless you export the function to the name you want to be. I.e Colors